# Why does the plug close again when $F_1$ equals weight of upper block?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics

[image]

In the picture can some explain me why the plug closes again when $F_1$ equals weight of upper block? I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, when the instantaneous buoyant force is greater than the weight of the cylinder (plus the rod and the plug), the cylinder accelerates upward. When the buoyant force is less than the weight of the cylinder, the cylinder accelerates downward until the plug hits the bottom.  You should be able to connect these concepts to the quantities $F_1$ and $F_2$.